# First time using Docker in linux and getting some errors

Tags: linux, docker

I have downloaded binaries from the website extracted it , and then added to the system path , 
now when i am doing 
`sudo dockerd &`
and i am getting this , see in this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGLee.png)

Comment: Do not use docker directly from downloaded binaries. Use the proper package manager in your distribution. Package manager will create necessary files and the init system (systemd) will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

[Biswapriyo](https://superuser.com/users/726810/biswapriyo) gave a nice and correct answer in a comment:

> Do not use docker directly from downloaded binaries. Use the proper package manager in your distribution. Package manager will create necessary files and the init system (systemd) will take care of the rest.